# How many electrons per second an electron beam generator needs to produce in order to obtain 7E-8 kg of positrons with a high energy laser?

Tags: mass-energy, estimation, antimatter

I have read that one way to produce antimatter  is pair  production through  the  use  of high   energy   lasers.   The   process consists in shooting a laser into  a  cloud   of   electrons,   which produces  a  series  of  gamma  rays. When  these  rays  collide  with  each other, they produce pairs of electrons and positrons, the latter of which can be   extracted   and   stored.

Some studies (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243532641_Pair_production_in_counterpropagating_electron_and_laser_beams) appear to indicate that a single seed electron could produce 30 electrons and 30 positrons, although I assume that higher energies would produce a higher amount of antimatter from a single electron seed.

Considering a *hypothetical* laser producing 1.34E+10 watts per second, I assume that the amount of antimatter produced  in  one  year  would be half of the following:

E=mc^2
m=E/c^2 = 4.2E+17 / 300,000,000^2 = 4.7 kg

But an electron beam generator would be needed to produce those electrons against which the photons would collide. How can I calculate how many electrons per second would I need if I want to produce 0.0000000745475 kg of positrons per second?

I would like to know that in order to calculate the power output of the electron beam generator.

Thank you.

Ps.: this isn't homework I was asked to do.

Comment: *energy of 1.34E+10 watts per second* Watts per second are not a unit of energy.

Comment: *0.000000149095 kg of positrons* Why that amount?

Comment: I meant 1.34E+10 watts per second.

Comment: actually 0,0000000745475 kg: it's the amount of antimatter produced every second with an input of 1.34E+10 watts according to E=MC^2

Comment: Does anybody know how can I calculate it?